# asp.net mvc testing: can't get access to object inside action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

having

```
public ActionResult Create(CategoryViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        Category category = new Category();
        category.Parent = daoTemplate.FindByID<Category>(viewModel.ParentId);
        category.CopyFrom(viewModel);
        daoTemplate.Save(category);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I need to ensure that newly created category has correct parent set. How can I do this, if I have no access to the category object outside of the method?

Comment: Could you clarify your question: how would you ensure it's the correct parent? You set it from the parent ID in the view model. Do you need to check if this is a valid parent for the category?

Comment: What unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: @Mike Scott I just need to somehow access category.Parent property in my test

Comment: @hmemcpy NUnit, but I need only basic idea of how such situations can be resolved

Comment: Sorry, I understand your question now. I'd pass the daoTemplate as a constructor parameter and mock it (I use Moq). The mocked Save method in your unit test can grab the category for later assertions in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the test you're proposing is really verifying two things:

1) `daoTemplate.FindByID<T>()` works as expected

2) The `Create` method calls `daoTemplate.FindByID<T>()`

Those should be two separate tests.

The first test should be part of a `DaoTemplate` fixture - apart from that it's difficult to comment on it without seeing more of the source code.

Second, to verify that the action calls the expected method, you'll need to hand-roll a mock object or use a mocking framework. There are numerous popular mocking frameworks for C# (Moq, RhinoMocks, even the venerable NMock2 - see the age-old stackoverflow question [What C# mocking framework to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-mocking-framework-to-use) for a start), and the classic place to get started mocking is Martin Fowler's article "[Mocks aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)."

Comment: Thanks,what if I want to verify if category has not null or empty name? should this logic go inside daoTemplate mock?

Comment: It depends on what sets the name - if it's `DaoTemplate.Save`, I'd test that logic in that method's test fixtures.